# My validation loss of my LSTM model is very volatile

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I'm creating an LSTM model to predict the closing price of bitcoin. However, when I started training, my validation loss starts getting very volatile and my test_prediction becomes inaccurate.

Here's my model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(80, input_shape=(1,look_back)))
model.add(LSTM(60))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Fitting the model:

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
callbacks = [ModelCheckpoint(save_best_only = True, filepath='btc_close_prediction.h5')]
history = model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, batch_size=10, epochs=30, callbacks=callbacks, validation_split=0.2)
```

loss graph:

[image: Loss Graph]

Prediction Plot:

[image]

Please advise how can I adjust my model for a better val_loss and better predicting accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation dataset should comprise of 5000 samples to get your validation loss smooth.

Try transformer model - it requires less training data.